# How to make a drop down content in Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I do have a Dialog with ScrollBar that has enough long content. It works perfect and now I want to add some more information in to this `dialog`. Adding new content is not a problem but I dont want it to be too long, so user will scroll it down until to interested place. So, I decided to divide my content to `three` parts. And when user will click on some Part, the information under that Part, will be shown. I will come out with 2 illustration of what i would like to have.
[image]

So, illustration number 2:

[image]

As you can see they will scrollDown after onClick and will show a content. I looked at `Spinner` but seems it is totally something else.  It is close to `Tabs` but I didnt see a vertical realization and also my app `minSdk` is 7. I would like to have some suggestions from you, which will suite my case in the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use **Expandable listview** in xml and bind it as `BaseExtendedAdapter`

here is [example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/)

try this [demo](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=28652&s=a5fc64500c422342c93165b0c38c2710)